# Kubernetes HorizontalPodAutoscaler for pods spawn by Airflow DAGs that uses KubernetesPodOperator

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, horizontalpodautoscaler

I have airflow using `CeleryExecutor` deployed in k8s cluster using `helm`. I have number of workers defined. I originally thought that this was the max number of workers but looks like the worker pods are always up. So this becomes a static number of workers. To resolve this static set of workers, I am looking for making it dynamic using `HorizontalPodAutoScaler`. Well, I am using `KubernetesPodOperator` which means the workers is not doing the work/task itself but will spin a new resource (Pod) for each task. So this becomes an issue for me implementing `HorizontalPodAutoScaler` because I need to scale the number of workers but since it's not the workers doing the work then it will not be able to measure the CPU/Memory usage correctly to scale up/down. I think `HorizontalPodAutoScaler` can be used for airflow running `KubernetesExecutor` but not sure about `CeleryExecutor`. Basically what I need is to implement `HorizontalPodAutoScaler` based on the metrics of the pods that the `KubernetesPodOperator` will  create and then increase/decrease the number of workers.

So how do I use `HorizontalPodAutoScaler` or if there is other alternative to make the worker size dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using KubernetesExecutor than no need to add HorizontalPodAutoScaler ,because it does scale pods based on matrix, technically KubernetesExecutor create new pod every time for DAG that going to be execute ,yes you can define resource in DAG for pod. If airflow deployed on kube then celeryExecutor not good idea.

Comment: Not really asking for what `KubernetesExecutor` can do. Hence the question about CeleryExecutor with `HorizontalPodAutoScaler`

Comment: then its depend upon what resources needs to run your DAG through CeleryExectuor. HorizontalPodAutoScaler scale up pod based on matrix . check resources consumption on prometheus . and update hpa based on that . normally hpa has 50% cpu , if more resources needed then it will look for now pod while it will reach to 100% meanwhile .